# What are the repercussions of changing the password on a Microsoft Account?

Tags: windows-8, passwords, windows-phone

I sign into Windows 8 with the same account as on my Windows Phone. I read the warnings that if I renamed my account to an outlook.com one, that I would have to do a hard reset on my phone and set it up again, from scratch. Are the consequences of changing just the password as severe, or will it "just work"?

Comment: Changing your password isn't the same as migrating to Outlook.com profile.

Comment: Just add the new ID as an `admin` **before** you change to the new one

Comment: See also: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1437/106

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote [the answer on the Stack Exchange site for Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1437/106)

> You just have to go into the settings of your phone and change the password and everything will work like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Changing the ID to one with a new domain (outlook.com) will not "just work", as you are changing your ID, but you definitely won't need to reinstall windows 8 from scratch.

In that case, you'd have to add your new ID as a new user with administrator rights before making the switch, and when done you could login with the migrated user.

You would lose all of the settings of the previous user, so make sure to move anything you might want out of your user folder first.

**However**, changing *only* the password just means than you need to be online for the first time afterwards to login with the new password, to let windows cache it.
Afterwards, you will have the new password even offline.

Comment: I'm asking here about the repercussions of changing the password, not changing the live id.

Comment: @RowlandShaw - There are no consequences of changing your password.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Microsoft Account to sign in to Windows 8, changing your Microsoft Account password will also change the password you use to log into your computer.

This also implies that if you forget the password for your PC, you can reset it on the web.

Comment: But will my phone still work?

Comment: @RowlandShaw It will show you the sign in dialog box for Windows Live. Sorry, but are you talking about changing your password or renaming your account?

Comment: Changing the password, hence "Are the consequences of changing just the password as severe, or will it "just work"?"

Comment: Okay, then yeah you're phone will work. Next time it tries to do something with the account (like download an app) it'll ask you for the password.

Answer (score -2):

Changing the ID means you will have to add the new ID as an `administrator` since for the application its just like a new user. If that is the case it means its a totally new set of user data specific to your previous ID .

Comment: I'm asking here about the repercussions (particularly for my phone) of changing the password, not changing the live id I use to sign in as.